# rsync, copy symlink as its original directory

Tags: rsync

I want rsync to copy my symlinks original directory name to the new destination.  I want to copy over the links I have in one directory and use those links to copy over just the directories that they link to, with their original name.

**Source Directory:**
default@ -> v1.2
previous@ -> v1.1
v1.0/
v1.1/
v1.2/

**What I want in Target Directory:** (I do something else for copying the default and previous links)
default@ -> v1.2
previous@ -> v1.1
v1.1/
v1.2/

I'm currently using this: (That one option is a capital i, not a lowercase L as it appears with this font)
**rsync -cIvrtRL /vol1/ALL/./dir1/dir2/dir3/default /vol2/new/ALL**

What I'm actually getting in my target directory is this:
(after copying over the symlinks default and previous with -l, then I get this)
default/
previous@ -> v1.1

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, or if something else is breaking this.

Thanks for any and all help!